# How to create a function that gets values from file, make them an struct array and return it?

Tags: arrays, c, struct, malloc

I have a source file named languages.c. I want to read the data/languages.txt text of get_availabile_languages () and create a Language struct array and define them in each element.

However, when I try to do this, I get a SIGSEGV error.
The code I created aims to do the following.

1. Start counting the rows. Create an element in `languages` with a `Language` sturct for each line.
2. use `strtok ()` to split the strings in `data/languages.txt` at the `=` sign. Assign the first to the `lang_code` variable and the second to `lang_name`.
3. When finished, return the struct array.

```c
/* main.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include "language.h"

int i;

int main ()
{
  puts ("--- Welcome to PiluX CLI installer ---");
  puts ("Language: ");
  // char* lang_name = get_language_name_from_code ("en");
  // char* lang_code = get_language_code_from_name ("English");
  // printf ("%s\n", lang_name);
  // printf ("%s\n", lang_code);
  Language *languages = get_available_languages ();
  printf ("%s\n", languages[0].name);
  free (languages);

  return 0;
}
```

```c
/* language.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <piluxsetup/language.h>


FILE* _open_languages_file ()
{
  /* 
    data/languages.txt dosyasını açar.
    Kodun tekrar tekrar yazılmaması için oluşturuldu.
  */
  FILE *supported_languages = fopen ("data/languages.txt", "r");
  
  if (!supported_languages)
  {
    printf ("\033[1;91mhata:\033[0m Language list can't open: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit (1);
  }

  return supported_languages;
}

char* get_language_name_from_code (char* code)
{
  /*
    Dil kodları arasından en yakın eşleşmeyi döndürür.
    Örnek:
    get_language_from_code ("de_DE"); -> Deutsh
  */

  FILE *supported_languages = _open_languages_file ();

  char *line;
  while (fgets (line, 80, supported_languages) != NULL)
  {
    if (strstr (line, code))
    {
      char* tokenizer = strtok (line, "="); // Birinci elemanı döndürür.
      return tokenizer;
      fclose(supported_languages);
    }
  }
  fclose(supported_languages);
  return "(not specified)";
}

char* get_language_code_from_name (char* name)
{
  /*
    Dil adları arasından en yakın eşleşmeyi döndürür.
    Örnek:
    get_language_from_name ("Türkçe"); -> tr_TR
  */

  FILE *supported_languages = _open_languages_file ();

  char *line;
  while (fgets (line, 80, supported_languages) != NULL)
  {
    if (strstr (line, name))
    {
      char* tokenizer = strtok (line, "=");
      tokenizer = strtok (NULL, "="); // sonraki parçayı işle
      tokenizer[strlen (tokenizer) - 1] = '\0'; // newline karakterini sil
      fclose(supported_languages);
      return tokenizer;
    }
  }
  fclose(supported_languages);
  return "(not specified)";
}

Language* get_available_languages ()
{
  FILE *supported_languages = _open_languages_file ();

  int line_count = 0;
  char line[80];

  char* lang_code = "";
  char* lang_name = "";
  Language* languages = malloc (sizeof (Language)*2);

  while (fgets (line, 80, supported_languages) != NULL)
  {
    ++line_count;
    char* tokenizer = strtok (line, "=");
    lang_code = tokenizer;
    tokenizer = strtok (NULL, "="); // sonraki parçayı işle
    lang_name = tokenizer;
    tokenizer[strlen (tokenizer) - 1] = '\0'; // newline karakterini sil

    languages = realloc (languages, line_count);

    strcpy (languages[line_count - 1].name, lang_name);
    strcpy (languages[line_count - 1].code, lang_code);
  }
  return languages;
}
```

```c
/* language.h */
typedef struct language
{
  char* name;
  char* code;
} Language;

char* get_language_name_from_code (char* code);
char* get_language_code_from_name (char* name);
Language* get_available_languages ();
```

```
# data/languages.txt
tr_TR=Türkçe
en_US=English
```

Output:

```bash
[alperen@LAPTOP-EDN1J28M setup]$ make clean && make
Artıklar temizleniyor...
rm -rf lib/* *.o piluxsetup
gcc -c language.c -Iincludes -Llib -lsetup  -fPIC
gcc -c partition.c -Iincludes -Llib -lsetup  -fPIC
gcc language.o partition.o -Iincludes  -shared -o lib/libpiluxsetup.so
gcc -c main.c -Iincludes -Llib -lpiluxsetup  -fPIC
gcc main.o -Llib -lpiluxsetup -Iincludes  -o setup
[alperen@LAPTOP-EDN1J28M distsetup]$ ./setup 
--- Welcome to installer ---
Language: 
Parçalama arızası (çekirdek döküldü)
[alperen@LAPTOP-EDN1J28M distsetup]$ gdb ./setup 
GNU gdb (GDB) Fedora Linux 13.2-2.fc38
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./setup...

This GDB supports auto-downloading debuginfo from the following URLs:
  <https://debuginfod.fedoraproject.org/>
Enable debuginfod for this session? (y or [n]) 
Debuginfod has been disabled.
To make this setting permanent, add 'set debuginfod enabled off' to .gdbinit.
(No debugging symbols found in ./piluxsetup)
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/alperen/Projeler/distsetup/piluxsetup 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
--- Welcome to installer ---
Language: 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strcpy_evex () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-evex.S:223
223             vmovq   %VMM_128(0), (%rdi)
(gdb)
```

Comment: How is the structure `Language` defined?

Comment: `char *line;` and `fgets (line, 80, supported_languages)`. You must allocate memory in one way or another for `fgets` to populate with data. Right now you are reading characters from a file and writing them to an effectively random location in memory.

Comment: `return tokenizer;` followed by `fclose(supported_languages);` - `strtok` tokenizes data in-place. Beware of returning a pointer to a local buffer, and note that you cannot execute function code after returning from the function, so that file handle will be leaked.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can be compiled if you want a complete answer, otherwise we can only really offer fragmented comments.

Comment: `realloc (languages, line_count);` - the second argument to `realloc` is the size of memory you want in *bytes*. There is no record of `malloc` being called with `sizeof (Language)`, so you must again include it in your calcuations (i.e., `realloc(languages, sizeof *languages * line_count)`).

Comment: I updated my code as reproducible.

Comment: It may now be reproducible but is certainly not minimal

Comment: `strcpy (languages[line_count - 1].name, lang_name);` follows the same issue of having no memory allocated for the destination. A `char *` is just a pointer. *You* have to ensure that it points to some valid memory if you want to store strings. Allocating memory for a `struct language` does not somehow provide any memory for its `char *` members to point to.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments, the most likely source of your segfault is here:

> ```
>   char *line;
>   while (fgets (line, 80, supported_languages) != NULL)
>   {
> ```

In this code `line` is a pointer to a `char` but it's uninitialized. It doesn't point to any valid memory. Now, it might by chance point to memory that allows it to "work" sometimes, but this should not be counted on.  Code like this "working" is the most dangerous thing it can do.

Instead you need to allocate memory for that read. You can do this on the stack or on the heap.

```
char line[80];
```

Or:

```
char *line = malloc(80);
```

As a pointer into `line` (via `strtok`) is returned and thus needs to survive the scope, you should opt for dynamic allocation with `malloc`. However, this cannot then be freed later as `line` itself becomes a dangling pointer.

You might instead read into a stack-allocated char array with `fgets` and then copy the actual desired string into a dynamically allocated char array of appropriate size, which can be returned. This will let you properly clean up your memory later.

Answer (score 0):

I added this piece of code to line 131.

```c
    languages[line_count - 1].name = malloc(strlen(lang_name) + 1);
    languages[line_count - 1].code = malloc(strlen(lang_code) + 1);
```

The `strcpy ()` function isn't seems copy the string to right address. So, I allocated temporary space from memory and copy the `lang_code` and `lang_name` to space. After that, I just returned the struct from function. However, I have to clear the temporary space with this function:

```c
void _free_available_languages (Language* language_list,
                                int len_language_list)
{
  int i = 0;
  for (; i < len_language_list; i++)
  {
    free(language_list[i].name);
    free(language_list[i].code);
  }
  free (language_list);
}
```